# Adding non-existent tags to interesting or ignored set

Tags: support, tag-watching, ignored-tags

When a user chooses an interesting/ignored tag, they can choose any tag. Even those which are not in the database or being used by any question.

As this is not creating a new tag, do these non-existent tags get searched for every time a user logs into the site and clicks on a question tab?

Answer (score 1):

I think we should test this!  I'm going to add `non-existent-tags` to my list, then check, add then retag this question to add `non-existent-tags`.  I will report back.

**Edit:**

Yes, this works as expected.  If a question is tagged with one of my interesting tags, even if it didn't exist before, it'll be highlighted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The highlighting/greying of interesting/ignored tags is all done client-side, so it's actually done every time you load a list of questions anywhere on the site (even in search results).

I think the lack of database-based tag support is partly because of this design, but also because you can do wildcard filtering on the tags (i.e., 'javascript*') where the input text won't exist as an actual tag in the database.